# My Brother DCP-7030 printer does not work

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

Unfortunately, I have downloaded the Ubuntu update, and since then my printer does not work. It seems the driver doesn't work, but the printer is shown to be on-line and ready to go.

Can anyone tell me how to download the correct driver and install it?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the contents of `cat /var/log/cups/*_log`?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to print? Does it print none stop with blank pages? What version of the driver are you using? I have had these problems with the Brother Printers.

Comment: On the PC the document gets sent to the printer, it enters the printer que and leaves the printer-que as if it is printed. However the printer shows no sing of receiving data and makes no attemt to print. Have deleted the printer and re-installed it so I guess a recent driver is used.

Comment: Go into your printer options click on your printer then browse the drivers, once you have load up the manufacturers, go to brother, and find your driver, see if it is set to the recommend under your model, if so try setting it to one of the other drivers in the model by double clicking the driver.